# Access REST end point on an embedded device using WiFi direct from android

Tags: android, rest, wifi, wifi-direct

I have an embedded device that exposes its functionalities via a RESTful Web service. I want to consume those Web services via my android device by connecting my mobile to the embedded device via Wifi? Is it possible to do so?

The possible use cases are transferring the control panel UI of the embedded device to the android and controlling it remotely. The UI is exposed as a REST endpoint.

Comment: why it shouldn't be possible? what's the chip model you are dealing with?

Comment: The device has ARM processor running on Win CE (Compact edition) OS

Comment: I can't find the exact device with the specification you gave to check if it has the necessary modules to do the functions, but if it can act as server or client, you can connect your android device to it for sure.

Comment: Ohh okay. Thanks much. But can we access the rest endpoints wirelessly? Is it possible? Is there any documentation or links you can point me to?

Comment: what do you mean by wirelessly? As far as I've seen, in 95% of projects android devices are connected to chips via wireless, unless there is Bluetooth or BLE, so if the first option is what you desire, confirm it so that I guide you further.

Comment: Yes. There is also a LAN connection to the embedded device. But I want to access the resources over a Wifi connection, preferably Wifi direct.

Comment: btw, using nanohttpd has some problem at first, if u are not using wifiDirect, I suggest you making android device the client and the chip server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the chip you are using supports Wi-Fi Direct, you should search for its code yourself since I don't know about it really, but you can find documentation and examples of wifi direct [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html), and if it doesn't support it, there are two scenarios, one is that you want to make your android device a server and your chip a client, which leads you to use [Nanohttpd](https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd) in your android code to make a server, and the other one is to bring up a server on your chip and make your android device a client, which leads to using a library like [loopj](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/) which saves lots of pain. so I guess that was all.

Comment: Thanks so much. I want to connect my android device as a client, since the embedded device itself will serve as an AP.

Comment: That'll save some pain, I hope you'll have no problem.